# Parsec.Expr repeated Prefix/Postfix operator not supported

Tags: haskell, parsec

The documentation for `Parsec.Expr.buildExpressionParser` says:

> Prefix and postfix operators of the same precedence can only occur
>   once (i.e. --2 is not allowed if - is prefix negate).

and indeed, this is biting me, since the language I am trying to parse allows arbitrary repetition of its prefix and postfix operators (think of a C expression like `**a[1][2]`).

So, why does `Parsec` make this restriction, and how can I work around it?

I think I can move my prefix/postfix parsers down into the `term` parser since they have the highest precedence.

i.e.

```
**a + 1
```

is parsed as

```
(*(*(a)))+(1)
```

but what could I have done if I wanted it to parse as

```
*(*((a)+(1)))
```

if `buildExpressionParser` did what I want, I could simply have rearranged the order of the operators in the table.

**Note** See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214163/parsec-expr-repeated-prefix-with-different-priority/33534426#33534426) for a better solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it myself by using `chainl1`:

```
prefix  p = Prefix  . chainl1 p $ return       (.)
postfix p = Postfix . chainl1 p $ return (flip (.))
```

These combinators use `chainl1` with an `op` parser that always succeeds, and simply composes the functions returned by the `term` parser in left-to-right or right-to-left order.  These can be used in the `buildExprParser` table; where you would have done this:

```
exprTable = [ [ Postfix subscr
              , Postfix dot
              ]
            , [ Prefix pos
              , Prefix neg
              ]
            ]
```

you now do this:

```
exprTable = [ [ postfix $ choice [ subscr
                                 , dot
                                 ]
              ]
            , [ prefix $ choice [ pos
                                , neg
                                ]
              ]
            ]
```

in this way, `buildExprParser` can still be used to set operator precedence, but now only sees a single `Prefix` or `Postfix` operator at each precedence.  However, that operator has the ability to slurp up as many copies of itself as it can, and return a function which makes it look as if there were only a single operator.

Comment: I found your answer extremely useful, but I ran into another problem, detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174775), and I'd appreciate it if you could take a look, on the off chance you have a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I am having a bit of difficulties with a generalisation of this problem. If you have any suggestions, they would be very welcome (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214163/parsec-expr-repeated-prefix-with-different-priority/33217888#33217888)