# How can I use buildExpressionParser from Text.Parsec.Expr to parse this language?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I've been trying to use buildExpressionParser to parse a language, and I almost have it. Thanks to [Parsec.Expr repeated Prefix/Postfix operator not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475337) for solving one of my big problems.

This code snippet illustrates (what I hope to be) my last difficulty:

```
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec

data Expr = Lit Char | A1 Expr | A2 Expr | B Expr Expr
  deriving (Show)

expr :: Parsec String () Expr
expr = buildExpressionParser table (fmap Lit digit)

prefix p = Prefix . chainl1 p $ return (.)

table =
  [ [prefix $ char ',' >> return A1]
  , [Infix   (char '*' >> return B) AssocNone]
  , [prefix $ char '.' >> return A2]]
```

This successfully (and correctly) parses `,,0`, `..0`, `.,0`, `.0*0`, and `,0*0`; it cannot, however, parse `,.0` or `.0*.0`. I can see why those two don't parse, but I don't see how I can change the parser so that none of the successes change and the two failures parse.

One way of "solving" this would be to change `(fmap Lit digit)` to `(fmap Lit Digit <|> expr)`, but then the parser would loop instead of erroring.

Advice welcome.

EDIT: The following parses are key:

```
> parseTest expr ".0*0"
A2 (B (Lit '0') (Lit '0'))

> parseTest expr ",0*0"
B (A1 (Lit '0')) (Lit '0')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get '.' and ',' on a level you could treat them together:

```
import Text.Parsec.Expr
import Text.Parsec

data Expr = Lit Char | A1 Expr | A2 Expr | B Expr Expr
  deriving (Show)

expr :: Parsec String () Expr
expr = buildExpressionParser table  (fmap Lit digit)
prefix p = Prefix . chainl1 p $ return (.)

table =
  [  [prefix $ (char ',' >> return A1) <|> (char '.' >> return A2)]
  , [Infix   (char '*' >> return B) AssocNone]
  , [prefix $ (char ',' >> return A1)] 
  ]

-- *Main> let f = parseTest expr
-- *Main> f ".,0"
-- A2 (A1 (Lit '0'))
-- *Main> f ".0*.0"
-- B (A2 (Lit '0')) (A2 (Lit '0'))
-- *Main> f ".0*,.0"
-- B (A2 (Lit '0')) (A1 (A2 (Lit '0')))
-- *Main> f ".,.0"
-- A2 (A1 (A2 (Lit '0')))
-- *Main> f ",.0"
-- A1 (A2 (Lit '0'))
```

Edit, this was the earlier obviously inadequate attempt

```
 table =
   [  [prefix $ (char ',' >> return A1) <|> (char '.' >> return A2)]
   , [Infix   (char '*' >> return B) AssocNone]
   ]
```

Comment: This changes the meaning of `,0*0` or `.0*0`, depending on which direction you move them.

Comment: I replaced it with a slightly different one; it does seem a bit of a hack.