# Why does only the first defined infix operator parse when using Parsec's buildExpressionParser?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to write a parser for the propositional calculus using Parsec. The parser uses the `buildExpressionParser` function from [Text.Parsec.Expr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Expr.html). Here's the code where I define the logical operators.

```
operators = [ [Prefix (string "~" >> return Negation)]
            , [binary "&" Conjunction]
            , [binary "|" Disjunction]
            , [binary "->" Conditional]
            , [binary "<->" Biconditional]
            ]

binary n c = Infix (spaces >> string n >> spaces >> return c) AssocRight

expr = buildExpressionParser operators term
    <?> "compound expression"
```

I've omitted the parsers for variables, terms and parenthesised expressions, but if you think they may be relevant to the problem you can read the [full source for the parser](https://gist.github.com/4191806).

The parser succeeds for expressions which use only negation and conjunction, i.e. the only prefix operator and the first infix operator.

```
*Data.Logic.Propositional.Parser2> runPT expr () "" "p & ~q"
Right (p ∧ ¬q)
```

Expressions using any other operators fail on the first character of the operator, with an error like the following:

```
*Data.Logic.Propositional.Parser2> runPT expr () "" "p | q"
Left (line 1, column 3):
unexpected "|"
expecting space or "&"
```

If I comment out the line defining the parser for conjunctions, then the parser for disjunction will work (but the rest will still fail). Putting them all into a single list (i.e. of the same precedence) doesn't work either: the same problem still manifests itself.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

---

Thanks to Daniel Fischer for such a prompt and helpful answer.

In order to finish making this parser work correctly, I also needed to handle repeated applications of the negation symbol, so that e.g. `~~p` would parse correctly. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475767/573562) showed me how to do it, and the change I made to the parser can be found [here](https://github.com/beastaugh/hatt/commit/580a1dc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
binary n c = Infix (spaces >> string n >> spaces >> return c) AssocRight
```

the first tried infix operator consumes a space before it fails, so the later possibilities are not tried. (Parsec favours consuming parsers, and `<|>` only tries to run the second parser if the first failed *without* consuming any input.)

To have the other infix operators tried if the first fails, you could either wrap the `binary` parsers in a `try`

```
binary n c = Infix (try $ ...) AssocRight
```

so that when such a parser fails, it does not consume any input, or, better, and the conventional solution to that problem, remove the initial `spaces` from it,

```
binary n c = Infix (string n >> spaces >> return c) AssocRight
```

and have all your parsers consume spaces *after* the token they parsed

```
variable = do c <- letter
              spaces
              return $ Variable (Var c)
        <?> "variable"

parens p = do char '('
              spaces
              x <- p
              char ')'
              spaces
              return x
        <?> "parens"
```

Of course, if you have parsers that can parse operators with a common prefix, you would still need to wrap those in a `try` so that if e.g parsing `>=` fails, `>>=` can still be tried.

Mocking up a datatype for the propositions and changing the space-consuming behaviour as indicated above,

```
*PropositionalParser Text.Parsec> head $ runPT expr () "" "p | q -> r & s"
Right (Conditional (Disjunction (Variable (Var 'p')) (Variable (Var 'q'))) (Conjunction (Variable (Var 'r')) (Variable (Var 's'))))
```

even a more complicated expression is parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Daniel. Solves the problem and also explains it. I'm very grateful.